# Undefined jquery push function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, push, undefined

here I create a code and function http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/10/ which must return me a arranged divs positions in arrays, but I get this errors when I chech in console log:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined**

```
rows[rowNumber].push(position);

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/10/embedded/result/

What is problem with that exaclty? How i can solve this?

Comment: I'll guess that your rownumber variable isn't what you think it is.

Comment: rownumber === -1 on second iteration

Comment: but here works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/6/, but when I chane values wont to work http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/6/

Answer (score 1):

Because `rows[rowNumber]` is not an array. You probably meant to do:

```
rows[rowNumber] = position;
```

Comment: not exactly ... look here http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/6/ here works fine, but when I change values , add neww ... dont work